# Rerender problems doesn't work in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have created `App.js` and `List.js` components. In `App.js` I created a state call `dark` to change the theme of `App.js` component. I put `List` componenent inside `App`. I wrapped `getItems` in `useMemo`. But when I just changed a theme the `List` component still rerender. I don't know why, can you explain for me.

```js
function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [dark, setDark] = useState(false);

  const getItems = useMemo(() => {
    return [number, number + 1, number + 2];
  }, [number]);

  const themeStyles = {
    backgroundColor: dark ? "black" : "white",
    color: dark ? "white" : "black",
  };

  return (
    <div style={themeStyles}>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={number}
        onChange={(e) => setNumber(parseInt(e.target.value))}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setDark((prevDark) => !prevDark)}>
        Change theme
      </button>
      <List getItems={getItems} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-chaum-ttmsh?file=/src/List.js

Comment: You're memoising getItems, so if number isn't changing you should find that the function isn't executing again. The List component is re-rendering because the parent (App) component is re-rendering due to state change. If you think that's a problem you could wrap your List component in React.memo but renders by themselves, for simple components are often not a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to memorize the component.

```
// List.js
import React, { memo } from "react";

const List = ({ getItems = [] }) => {
  console.log("List is rerendering");
  const list = getItems.map((item) => {
    return <p key={item}>{item}</p>;
  });
  return <div>{list}</div>;
};

export default memo(List);
```